# Approach to handle/reassemble TCP Segmented packets at Server, after returns from Select call

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming

1. Client shall be sending TCP data(SIP Message) around 5K bytes in the form of multiple segments.
2. What shall be the best approach at server side to re-assemble the segments.

NOTE: 
1. It would be great if the approach is without packet sniffing
2. Performance also needs to be considered while addressing.
3. Implementation considerations: C, C++

We have tired to handle at sip protocal stack side but results are not so great.
So thinking if it can be handle it by implementing a Wrapper after Linux "Select Call" that re-assembles the complete Packet received on each file descriptor & perform further processing.

Comment: Is the usual “call recv() until you have received all the bytes you need” approach not sufficient!

Comment: You don't have to reassemble the packets. TCP is a connection oriented stream protocol. TCP is guaranteed to do it for you. Did you mean UDP/Datagram service? UDP is fire and forget.

Comment: "Is the usual “call recv() until you have received all the bytes you need” approach not sufficient! " - Yes, it was'nt. As "recv" call is expected to happen for each segement but not after complete packet re-assembly.

Comment: I think you may be confused about how tcp works — there is no such thing as packet reassembly for tcp.  Rather, bytes are delivered in FIFO order, without any fixed message boundaries.  If you need message framing, that is something you have to implement for yourself at the application level, based on the data you get from the recv() calls.

Answer (score 1):

For SIP message you have to parse at least the SIP headers.
do recv until the value mentioned in **Content-Length**.

Without interpreting the Content-Length you cannot identify the actual length of the SIP message packet.